# Loading state in react: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

How do I prevent the following error:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.'

**My code:**

```
function App() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    if (items.length == 0) loadMore()
    return <div>
        {isLoading
            ? <div>Loading...</div>
            : <ol>{items.map(i => <li>{i}</li>)}</ol>
        }
        <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={loadMore} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            {isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Load again"}
        </button>
    </div>;

    function loadMore() {
        setIsLoading(true); // ⚠ errors!
        const uri = "https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json";
        fetch(uri)
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(r => {
                const newItems = r.data.children.map(i => i.data.title);
                items.push(...newItems);
                setItems([...items]);
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    }
}
```

[Stackblitz link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-c5dzqk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of this condition `if (items.length == 0) loadMore()`.

Because at the beginning the length is 0, loadMore is called in which you set the state and you enter the condition again which call loadMore and so on.

Use the `useEffect` hook with an empty array of dependencies instead of the condition which will call the function once when the component mount.

```
useEffect(loadMore, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer of [@tarek-essam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10443105/tarek-essam)

and adding more into it that you can not mutate the state directly in React...

change loadMore() function to this:

```
    function loadMore() {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const uri = "https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json";
        fetch(uri)
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(r => {
                const newItems = r.data.children.map(i => i.data.title);
                setItems([...items, ...newItems]);
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    }
```

so the complete solution is:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await loadMore())();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <ol>
          {items.map(i => (
            <li>{i}</li>
          ))}
        </ol>
      )}
      <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={loadMore}>
        {isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Load again"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );

  function loadMore() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const uri = "https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs.json"; // using vue js cause reactjs json is not working in my machine 
    fetch(uri)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r => {
        const newItems = r.data.children.map(i => i.data.title);
        setItems([...items, ...newItems]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```